# How to run a Kotlin server generated by Swagger Codegen?

Tags: kotlin, swagger-codegen

I am unable to run the `kotlin-server` generated by Swagger Codegen v. 3.

The `.yaml` file is:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Experiement with Swagger
  description: Test
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8080'
    description: production server's url
tags:
  - name: Test
    description: Test
    externalDocs:
      description: Find out more
      url: 'http://localhost:8080'
paths:
  /testURI:
    post:
      tags:
        - Test
      summary: Test
      description: Test
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Test'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Test success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/TestSuccessResponse'
        '404':
          description: >-
            Only a signed in user can add a question. This response means that
            the user isn't signed in.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UnauthorisedErrorResponse'
        '500':
          description: >-
            means some internal error occur on the server while doing the
            operation. The state of the operation if un-determined and the
            operation could be succesful, failed or partially successful
            (because some database operations are not rolled back if error
            occurs!
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/InternalServerErrorResponse'


components:
  schemas:
    Test:
      type: object
      properties:
        some-input:
          type: string

    TestSuccessResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: string
          enum:
            - success
        additional-info:
          type: string
          enum:
            - Test successful
      required:
        - result
        - additional-info
    UnauthorisedErrorResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: string
          enum:
            - error
        additional-info:
          type: string
          enum:
            - Not authorised
      required:
        - result
        - additional-info
    InternalServerErrorResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: string
          enum:
            - error
        additional-info:
          type: string
          enum:
            - Internal Server Error
      required:
        - result
        - additional-info
```

I pasted it into Swagger Editor, downloaded the `kotlin-server` `kotlin-server-server-generated.zip`, unzipped it at `C:\Users\manu\Documents\manu\kotlin-server-server-generated`, opened `Readme.MD` file and followed the instructions in it.

Using Windows `cmd`, in `C:\Users\manu\Documents\manu\kotlin-server-server-generated`,
first I ran `gradle wrapper`.

I got this output:

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>   Build cache is an incubating feature.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
>   1 actionable task: 1 executed

Then I ran `gradlew check assemble`:

> C:\Users\manu\Documents\manu\kotlin-server-server-generated>gradlew check assemble
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>   Build cache is an incubating feature.
>   w: C:\Users\manu\Documents\manu\kotlin-server-server-generated\src\main\kotlin\io\swagger\server\apis\TestApi.kt: (51, 9): Variable 'gson' is never used
>   w: C:\Users\manu\Documents\manu\kotlin-server-server-generated\src\main\kotlin\io\swagger\server\apis\TestApi.kt: (52, 9): Variable 'empty' is never used
>
> Task :startShadowScripts
>   Using TaskInputs.file() with something that doesn't resolve to a File object has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Use TaskInputs.files() instead.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 36s
>   10 actionable tasks: 10 executed

Then I ran `java -jar ./build/libs/kotlin-server.jar`.

But when I pointed the browser to `localhost:8080`, I see `Page Not Found`.

What am I doing wrong?